# css: positioning in relative to other elements

Tags: html, css

Assume I have two elements, div1 and div2 and I have defined the css for div1. I want to specify the position of div2 relative to div1, for example say div2 should be 30px to the left of div1.   Is this possible?

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: impossible to say without more details. is `div2` inside `div1`? are they next to each other? do they have the same parent and is the parent positioned? do you know the heights and widths?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. set the position of div 1 to relative. Set the position of div2 to absolute with the left value of 30px. Div2 will be positioned absolutely not to the body, but to the parent div which has a position of relative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (unless I'm really simplifying your question):

`div1 { position: absolute; left:0; top:0; }`

`div2 { position: relative; left:30px; }`

Answer (score 0):

If div1 is exactly where you need to be on the page already, then I think Phil's answer with position: relative is the correct one. If that's not it, here are a few other alternatives.

Clarifying question, are you wanting div2 to appear 30px to the left of div1, or do you want div2 to have a 30px left margin to space it out on the right side of div1?

If it's the former, make sure div2 is before div1 in your html, and try this:

```
div1, div2 { float: left; }
div2 { margin-right: 30px; }
```

If it's the latter, make sure div1 is before div2, and try something like this:

```
div1, div2 { float: left; }
div2 { margin-left: 30px; }
```